# Как сделать чтобы при появлении слайдер толкнул кнопку вниз

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть блок по `5` картинками и описанием.

Под этим блоком есть кнопка в которую если нажмете то внизу появляется плавно дополнительно еще такой блок.Как сделать чтобы при появлении этого блока он толкал кнопку вниз .То есть таких блоков может быть `500` и будут они появлятсья по `5` а кнопка всегда должна быть внизу

Помогите пожалуйста

Посмотрите на полную ширину чтобы понять суть вопроса а то в маленьких экранах не очень .

```js
// 
var b = $('body');
var isToggled = false; //
var origTextStr = b.find('button').text();

$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
 
 var t = $(this),
   next = t.nextAll('.group:first'),
   nextObj = t.nextAll('.design_block');
 
 // изменить текст кнопки при клике на него
 if( !isToggled ) { t.text('Hide more'); } else { t.text(origTextStr); }
 
 //взять высоту блока
 var nextHeight = next.height() + 'px';
 
 // добавить трансформ на  'next'
 if( !isToggled ){
  nextObj.css('transform', 'translateY('+ nextHeight +')');
  next.addClass('on');
  //добавить класс  ('on');
  isToggled = true;
 }
 else {
  nextObj.css('transform','translateY(0)');
  next.removeClass('on');
  isToggled = false;
 }
 
});
```

```css
body.on {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.our_works {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.our_works .design_block {
  width: 210px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.our_works .architecture_img {
  width: 210px;
  height: 198px;
}
.our_works .more_posts {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #2a323d;
  padding: 12px 0 13px 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.our_works .more_posts a {
  color: #fff;
}
.our_works .more_posts a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.group .design_block {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100px);
  visibility: hidden;
}
.group .design_block:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.group .design_block:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.group.on .design_block {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  visibility: visible;
}

.design_block {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="our_works">
      
      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
      </div>


      <!-- Button goes here -->
      <button class="more_posts">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a>
      </button>
      
      <!-- hidden blocks -->
    <div class="group">
      
      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
      </div>
 </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Где находится кнопка?

Comment: @RomanC да там даже комментарии есть как можно не видеть это?

Comment: Вынести кнопку за пределы блока `.our_works`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko точно ?а попытайтесь сделать сами смотрите что выйдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как было сказано, кнопку лучше всего вынести за пределы блока `.our_works`. Тогда она вегда будет снизу, в независимости от количества блоков.

Пример.

```js
// 
var b = $('body');
var isToggled = false; //
var origTextStr = b.find('button').text();

$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {

  var t = $(this),
    next = $('.our_works .group:not(.on):first');

  //взять высоту блока
  var nextHeight = 340; // Здесь надо вычислить высоту блока. Пока что хард кодом забьем

  next.addClass('on');
  next.height(nextHeight);

  if (!$('.our_works .group:not(.on):first').length) { //Больше блоков на показ нету
    t.hide("hide_opacity");
  }

});
```

```css
body.on {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.our_works {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.our_works .design_block {
  width: 210px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.our_works .architecture_img {
  width: 210px;
  height: 198px;
}

.more_posts {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #2a323d;
  padding: 12px 0 13px 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: opacity 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
}

.more_posts a {
  color: #fff;
}

.more_posts a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
}

.group .design_block {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100px);
}

.group .design_block:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.group .design_block:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.group.on .design_block {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.design_block {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="our_works">

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
      </div>

      <div class="design_block">
        <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
        <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
        <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
      </div>




      <!-- hidden blocks -->
      <div class="group">

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- hidden blocks -->
      <div class="group">

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- hidden blocks -->
      <div class="group">

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- hidden blocks -->
      <div class="group">

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE + DESIGN</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Faye Toogood Gives This Mediterranean Vacation Home a Total Makeover</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">ARCHITECTURE</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">How This Derelict Paris District Transformed Into the Start-Up Capital of France</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY HOMES</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">Leonardo DiCaprio Just Bought Moby's Los Feliz House—But He May Never Even Live in It</div>
        </div>

        <div class="design_block">
          <img src="http://architectureimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ancient-watermill-trees-cascades-stones-creek-nature-free-download-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="" class="architecture_img">
          <h6 class="design_block_title">CELEBRITY LIFESTYLE</h6>
          <div class="preview_design_block">This Charming Welsh Cottage Is Only Accessible by Steam Train</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Button goes here -->
    <button class="more_posts">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое я выводил просто он не работал а js-ом написать не получилось плюсик от меня